# python socketio Server with custom mainloop

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket.io, aiohttp, python-socketio

## simplified use case

I have multiple (slow) robots, an API for the robots to upload sensor data and one control loop for all robots running on the server. The setup that I want to create looks something like this:

Robot emits event with new sensor data. server catches event and saved data in queue. Control loop reads data from queue and writes actuator commands to queue. Server reads queue and emits event with new actuator commands. The robot then executes those commands.

## simplified code

Note: Control loop is not shown. It runs completely independent in a different `multiprocessing.Process`. `q_in` is a `multiprocessing.Queue` that is read by the control loop. `q_out` contains the results of the control loop.

```py
def io_server(q_out, q_in):
    sio= socketio.AsyncServer()
    app = aiohttp.web.Application()
    sio.attach(app)
    
    @sio.event
    def connect(sid, environ):
        pass
    
    @sio.event
    def disconnect(sid):
        pass
    
    @sio.event
    def my_event(sid, data):
        nonlocal q_in
        q_in.put(data)
    
    async def send_loop():
        nonlocal q_out
        while True:
            logger.log('x')
            if not q_out.empty():
                actuator_data = q_out.get()
                await sio.emit('robot_event', actuator_data )
            await collective.sleep(0.0001)
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_forever()
    asyncio.create_task(send_loop())
    asyncio.create_task(aiohttp.web.run_app(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5678))
```

This code does not work. I neither receives, nor emits events.
It does however receive events when the following three lines are removed.

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_forever()
asyncio.create_task(send_loop())
```

I need new ideas how to fix or prevent this issue.

Is it possible to create something like this?

```py
while True:
    aiohttp.web.run_single_loop(...)
    send_single_loop()
```

Comment: I don't really follow what you want to do. Socket.IO works on HTTP and WebSocket. If you are trying to have a Socket.IO server with the HTTP/WS interface somewhere else, that is possible, but not directly supported by python-socketio.

Comment: @Miguel I have a control loop that needs to emit an event to the client, but the `AsyncServer` instance is not thread safe, so I can not access it from within the control loop. To put it in different words: I want to run a cron-job on the server.

Comment: See the documentation for emitting from an external process. I think that's what you need in this case.